# How to get a date picker for dates?

Tags: date, data-binding, grails

I want to replace the default Grails datePicker with the jQuery UI one. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I get the popup onto the page but the data binding to the domain seems to be a pain (the easiest way is to do something like described here: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2011/12/29/grails-custom-data-binding-in-3-simple-steps/ but I'm looking for a simpler solution like a plugin which provides a tag).

I looked at Grails UI and Rich UI plugins but their date pickers are crappy (one has time fields outside the popup and the outer one has an icon and a close button... I really want the jQuery UI popup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (for me) is to do data binding like this:

```
def authorInstance = new Author()
bindData(authorInstance, params, [exclude: 'dateOfBirth'])
bindData(authorInstance, ['dateOfBirth': params.date('dateOfBirth', ['dd-MMM-yyyy'])], [include: 'dateOfBirth'])
```

So I can use any date/time picker I like, just change the date format in the last line (this date format can be specified in `messages.properties` to make that line a bit shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Simple ...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#paymentDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
            changeYear:true,
            changeMonth:true
        });

    });
</script>
```

....

```
<g:textField id="paymentDate" name="paymentDate" value="${beanInstance?.paymentDate?.format("dd-MMM-yyyy")}"/>
```

Comment: I know that this part is simple, but I don't think that the data binding will work (Grails expects 3 dropdowns just like `g:datePicker` creates).

Comment: Create simple example and check (I have many datePickers implemented like this in my project) ...

Comment: It just says 'Property dateOfBirth must be a valid Date'

Comment: you need to add CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar described in link below

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-1-1-change-in-binding-date-properties-td1323105.html

Comment: As I said it the question, I know how to do it that way as well... I was looking for an easier way (I thought that a lot of people would be doing the same thing and there was a way without manually creating the registrar).

Comment: You can also use org.joda.time.LocalDate class for your instead of java.util.Date. in this case you don't need registrar